# Handling exceptions and rollbacks in MVC3 with NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, transactions

I'm using a transaction-per-action filter in MVC3 like Ayende [describes](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/04/12/refactoring-toward-frictionless-amp-odorless-code-what-about-transactions.aspx) and wondered how others handle exceptions and rollbacks.

The action filter will learn about an exception from the filterContext object, and will automatically rollback the transaction. But if I handle the exception in my action, then that doesn't happen.

I've thought of using HttpContext.Current.Items to stash a flag of some sort that the transaction failed, and then having my action filter check for it, but that's a kludge I'd prefer to avoid.

Can anyone offer me advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

[Sharp architecture](https://github.com/sharparchitecture) provides [IDbContext](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/blob/master/src/SharpArch/SharpArch.Data/NHibernate/DbContext.cs) to do this.

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I really desire to get the underlying session, that's not a problem. I'm just wondering if anyone has a solution that will allow me to keep the seamless nature of the filter's transaction management without sacrificing flow control.

Answer (score 0):

On controller you can override OnResultExecuted for a safe area to dispose your context, or to rollback your transaction or whatever unit of work related.

Comment: Thanks, but the transaction creation, rollback and commit happens on the transaction-per-action filter. I just want a way to flag the action as failing without either throwing an exception or allowing one to go unhandled.